# Validate Form using PHP on JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is there a way i can call a php function on my javascript?

i was trying to embed Cryptographp captcha on my existing form, it says there that i should use the syntax below

I have my form and JS validation on the same page. The captcha is displaying already but i'm figuring out how to include it on my validation script which i think is jquery. here is the structure.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[

    function checkMe(frm) {

        var error = '';
        var errormsg = '<?php echo "Blah Blah";?>';

        if (!frm.name.value) error += '<li class=error>&raquo; Input Your Name </li>';
        if (!frm.phone.value) error += '<li class=errlist>&raquo; Input Your Phone</li>';

        if (error) {
            document.getElementById('msgError').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('msgError').innerHTML = errormsg + error;
            //alert(error);
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Can i add php on if statement like this?

```
if (<?php if (chk_crypt($_POST['code'])) echo "Correct"; else echo "Bad :("; ?>) == false) {
    error += '<li class=errlist>&raquo; Wrong Captcha</li>';
```

i would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can't execute PHP in JavaScript; that's not how the server-client model works. You can **generate** JavaScript with PHP, but you can't interpret PHP in JavaScript. PHP will always be evaluated first. I suggest you look into AJAX and JSON.

Comment: any suggestion to correct my code?

Comment: @TheDon Yes. Treat it like the PHP will always execute first.

Comment: in javascript/jquery: When the captcha submit is clicked, (prevent default submit action), do an ajax post to another php page that will validate it and send back a status (good/bad), then use that status to display your message to the user.  Or... in javascript do `captcha = '<?php echo $_POST['code'] ?>'` then in your if statement do... `if (captcha == user_input) ...`

Comment: @elclanrs is right but you can use `ajax` request to actually call php validation code from javascript.